# GPS coordinate based makrer placing on road

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Greeting, everyone!

I am trying to build an navigation app using Google Maps Android V2 as the source for maps, also using Google Directions service for receiving routes.

I have one problem, where I am really stuck for now. I've been searching internet for weeks, trying to make it happen in different ways - not successful yet.

So the problem is that, marker which is placed on map according to GPS coordinates could be placed next to street not on street. This is the problem. I've been looking into ways to get this done. One possible way is snapping coordinate to road. I can achieve that using Google Directions service and getting starting location which is not ok, because it uses network data on each GPS location change event, or I can use OSM (Open Street Maps) data, to get the road, which fails for me, because marker is still placed not exactly where I wanted, but is better than nothing. Also, I think that it could be promising if I checked whether GPS accuracy is smaller than distance to road, because not always user will be on road. Any suggestions on achieving this? Links, articles, libraries, another expierenced info.

Also, another thing is rotating map on the direction user drives. What is best practices on doing it? Classing bearing is working bad, because it could turn around while I am standing still.

Thanks, Kedarnath, for Your suggestion to paste code.
http://pastebin.com/J6rnFgax - here is my implementation of LocationListener class.
Methods, where should be changes according to my problem, are setUpMarker and setUpMap.
Method, getRoadCoordinates, acquires data from OSM so no internet connection is needed.

Thank You in advance guys,
Daniels.

Comment: Daniels , Please post some code in question and error log if any.